Invalid address access on Coldfire MCF5307
I try to understand what an invalid address access is doing on a MCF5307.
The RAMBAR register is 0x90000001. Internal SRAM is used only for the stack.
My software is doing a stack overflow so it is doing an access to 0x8FFFFFxx.
No chip select is mapped @ 0x8FFFFFxx
The MBAR register is 0x80000000 but it is only 4KB as fas as I understood.
The user manual describes how chip select are selected but there is no mention of RAMBAR or MBAR:

On my debugger when I do an access to 0x8FFFFFxx the CPU hangs but several instructions later. I am more used to ARM processors where such invalid access would raise en exception.
What exactly happens when the (invalid ?) address 0x8FFFFFxx is accessed?
Also, what means "external burst-inhibited bus cycle" in the user manual extract?
